# Unity2D: currentSelectedGameObject panel disabled

Tags: unity-game-engine

Okay, so I have a click to move game and a panel in which I do not want my player to move towards. However the panel is disabled at first (for an effect I'm doing) until the user clicks on a button to SetActive the panel. I used currentSelectedGameObject to block my player going to towards the panel but it isn't working, maybe because the panel was disabled in the first place, I not sure just spitting out ideas. Hopeful someone can help me.

```
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public GameObject currentSelectedGameObject;

public void Update () {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
        if (EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject)
            return;
                    Vector3 mousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
                    mousePosition.z = 10; // distance from the camera
                    target = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (mousePosition);
                    target.z = transform.position.z;
    }

                    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards (transform.position, target, speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
   }
```

Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the button to setactive the panel and if not , you are not using the public GameObject currentSelectedGameObject variable in your code , do this :

```
if (EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject == currentSelectedGameObject) // now this is your variable that you declared being used in the if statement
```

I cant remember correctly but mb its like this    EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject.name

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, however I didn't really work